# Solr dismax Query Over Multiple Fields

Tags: solr, dismax

I am trying to do a solr dismax query over multiple fields, and am a little confused with the syntax.

My core contains a whole load of podcast episodes. The fields in the index are EPISODE_ID, EPISODE_TITLE, EPISODE_DESC, and EPISODE_KEYWORDS.

Now, when I do a query I would like to search for the query term in the EPISODE_TITLE, EPISODE_DESC, and EPISODE_KEYWORDS fields, with different boosts for the different fields.

So when I search for 'jedi', the query I've built looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/episode_core/select?
    &defType=dismax&q=jedi&fl=EPISODE_ID,EPISODE_TITLE,EPISODE_DESC,EPISODE_KEYWORDS
    &qf=EPISODE_TITLE^3.0+EPISODE_DESC^2.0+EPISODE_KEYWORDS
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - it returns zero records.

When I put a default field like below, it now works, but this is kind of crap because it means I'm not getting results from searching all of the 3 fields:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/episode_core/select?&df=EPISODE_DESC
    &defType=dismax&q=jedi&fl=EPISODE_ID,EPISODE_TITLE,EPISODE_DESC,EPISODE_KEYWORDS
    &qf=EPISODE_TITLE^3.0+EPISODE_DESC^2.0+EPISODE_KEYWORDS
```

Is there something I am missing here? I thought that you could search over multiple fields, and I thought that the 'qf' parameter would mean you didn't need to supply the default field parameter?

All help much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct. If you've defined *qf* (query fields) for Dismax, there shouldn't be any need to specify a *df* (default field).

---

Can you be more specific about what isn't working?

---

Also, read up on [Configuration Invariants](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler) in `solrconfig.xml` as it is possible your configuration could be sending some different parameters than you've specified in the URL.

(E.g. if you're seeing a specific error message asking you to provide a *df*)

Comment: Yes - will edit the question now - was extremely tired when I wrote this. It's a little unclear... Tom

Comment: It returns zero records, even though we know there are lots in the index that match the query.

Comment: Quick debugging:   Change `q=*:*` (match all) and make sure you've got data in the index.   If you've got data, then it's back to the analysis page (mentioned w your prev solr post) to see the impact of your analyzer setup in scheme.xml.

Comment: You can also pass `debugQuery=true` as a param and see how "jedi" gets rewritten across your three fields.

Comment: If your schema.xml is still the same as from your other post, `debugQuery=true` will help you make sure you're not getting tripped up by case-sensitive field names.   (E.g use `episode_desc` etc instead of the all-caps)

Comment: The debugQuery stuff worked for me - it seems I was making a very stupid error - the query field which was being determined programmatically wasn't getting the value I thought  for the query without that df field. Total moron! Thanks anyways - I'll ship you the bonus!